# Retrieve arguments for android:entries

Tags: android

I'm subclassing the `Spinner` class, and I need to get the objects specified in the xml file by `android:entries`. How can I do that?

```
<com.myapp.MySpinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/myarray"/>
```

So I need either the array specified in the `entries` argument, or the resourceid so I can fetch them myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override constructor of `Spinner` and retrieve entries from the `AttributeSet` param.

```
public class MySpinner extends Spinner {
    public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        if (attrs != null) {
            final int[] ids = {android.R.attr.entries};
            final TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ids);
            final int entriesId = array.getResourceId(0, 0);

            if (entriesId > 0) {
                final Resources resources = context.getResources();
                final String[] entries = resources.getStringArray(entriesId);

                if (entries != null) {
                    // do whatever you want here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the `ids` parameter.